# Drillthrough Action active while working with Cube Formulas and Slicer in Pivot Table

Tags: sql, excel, ssas, pivot-table, business-intelligence

Let's say we've build the following report `Pivot Table` with `Slicer` Cost Centers based on `SSAS Cube` : [image]

As we can observ there are `Drillthrough Actions` available, so that the users can see details associated with the selected Cost Center.

After we converted the `Pivot Table` to cube formulas because of complexity of the reports, the `Drillthrough Actions` are not available anymore. They were disabled like in the second picture.

I checked the Cube Formula and it's looked like this:

```
=CUBEVALUE( "CUBE";$B13;C$5;Slicer_Cost_Center_No )
```

The `Slicer` was passed as Parameter after converting to formula. If we try `Drillthrough` now , it's disabled. But if we remove the Slicer from formula and  pass the cost center manually, the `Drillthrough` will became active again.

How can we keep the `Drillthrough Action` active while still working with `Cube Formulas` and `Slicer` as Filter?

[image]

`Drillthrough` will became active without `Slicer` in `Formula`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try Excel 2016 and SSAS 2016. This combo allows drillthrough on cells minding filters set on slicer. You can run Excel 2016 on SSAS 2014 or 2012, in such case drillthrough will not honor slicer filter set.